# Displaying a point with latitude and longitude with custom address text

Tags: html, google-maps

I know I can input the address to the URL like below to get the pointer point to the place

```
<iframe src='@string.Format("https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=somekey&q={0}", Addressstring)' width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
```

However, I found the marking not so accurate. So I went for the option to put the latitude and longitude

```
<iframe src='@string.Format("https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=somekey&q={0},{1}", Latitude, Longitude)' width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
```

I want to show the address as well as the pointer from latlng.

Is there a way to display the address(or maybe hide the latitude and logitude text) in the map on the top left corner as well as the pointer pointing the lat long that I had set?

Thanks a lot for help!!

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to put in the Latitudes and Longitudes in the URL you have formed in order to display a specific position in map, you can always put the address separated by a "+" sign. That way the numeric value of the latitude and longitude wont be visible in your map at anytime.

Here is a code snippet to achieve this:

```
<iframe
  width="600"
  height="450"
  frameborder="0" style="border:0"
  src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=API_KEY
    &q=Space+Needle,Seattle+WA">
</iframe>
```

For more information please refer to the following [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide).

Hope this would Help!!

Comment: Is is possible to use the latitude and longitude for the pointer while displaying the name of the address(or some custom text)?